# A multivalued function $ f(x) = 0 $ with integer solutions $ x_1=p(n) $ and $x_2=q(n) $

Tags: prime-numbers, primitive-roots, multivalued-functions

Please help me to define a multivalued function $ f(x) = 0 $ with integer solutions :

$ x_1 = p(n)$  and $ x_2 = q(n) $

such that

$\dfrac{ p(n) + q(n) } { 2 } = 2 n + 1 $

and

$ \operatorname{Mod}[p(n)^2-q(n)^2, 2 n + 1] = 0 $

> $p(n)=
> \{3, 5, 7, 3, 11, 13, 9, 17, 19, 17, 23, 5, 17, 29, 31, 3, 33, 37, 29,
> 41, 43, 35, 47, 9, 3, 53, 19, 3, 59, 61, 3, 5, 67, 45, 71, 73, 29,
> 53, 79, 71,\dots\}$
>
> $q(n)=
> \{3, 5, 7, 15, 11, 13, 21, 17, 19, 25, 23, 45, 37, 29, 31, 63, 37, 37,
> 49, 41, 43, 55, 47, 89, 99, 53, 91, 111, 59, 61, 123, 125, 67, 93,
> 71, 73, 121, 101, 79, 91,\dots\}$

Update :

For $ n=4  $ we get :

$  (p(4),q(4))->(3,15)$

$ \operatorname{Mod}[15^2-3^2, 9] = 0 $

The solution  $(9,9)$ is not of interest because 9 is not a prime number.

Only when $ 2 n + 1 $ is an odd prime $ p(n) = q(n) $

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you explain how (3,15) works? (n=4) And why (9,9) is not acceptable in that case?

Comment: I forgot to mention that only when $2 n +1 $ is prime $p(n) = q(n) = 2 n +1$.